# Heißt es Schinken-Käse- oder Käse-Schinken-Croissant?

Tags: word-order

Gibt es eine (Faust)Regel, welche Eigenschaft bei derartig zusammengesetzten Wörtern zuerst genannt wird?

Comment: Hauptsache, der Bindestrich wird richtig verwendet :)

Comment: Immer Fleisch vor Wurst, Wurst vor Käse, Käse vor Obst, Obst vor Gemüse. Pilze zählen wie Käse und gleiche Kategorien werden alphabetisch sortiert.

Comment: @userunknown: Wo hast du das her?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpkGQUqnotg

Comment: Weder _"Schinken"_ noch _"Käse"_ sind _Eigenschaften_.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Rat mal. :)

Comment: /OT @userunknown Fleischliebhaber? BTW: Nur Fleisch mit Käse bringt's wirklich (evtl. noch ein Spiegelei obendrauf). Vegan ist _Bäh_ ;-). Deine Kommentare sind nicht unbedingt substantiell meistens, aber lustig!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Vegan ist total super. Für's Klima. Wenn es andere machen. :) Meine Kommentare sind übrigens meistens substantiell und nicht lustig, weswegen ich selten über 0-2 Upvotes hinauskomme. :) Dieser war eine Ausnahme.

Comment: /OT @userunknown _"Ich hätte hier noch von den lecker Saitan Medallions oder Halloumi, mag das jemand bevor's komplett verkohlt? Es gibt auch Grillgurke dazu!"_ Best chance you'll never get onto that yummy steak you've reserved for yourself ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Heißt es Schinken-Käse- oder Käse-Schinken-Croissant?

Beide Bezeichnungen werden im praktischen Sprachgebrauch gleichwertig verwendet.

> Gibt es eine (Faust)Regel, welche Eigenschaft bei derartig zusammengesetzten Wörtern zuerst genannt wird?

Soweit es mir bekannt ist, gibt es keine allgemein gültige Faustregel hierfür.

Dennoch hat sich bei bestimmten zusammengesetzten Begriffen eine Präferenz durchgesetzt, so wird zum Beispiel der Begriff

> > Rot-Grün-Blindheit

bevorzugt<sup>1</sup> gegenüber

> > Grün-Rot-Blindheit

verwendet.

Ich nehme an, dass sich in diesem Fall der erste Begriff einfach vom Sprachgebrauch her durchgesetzt hat.
Eventuell hat es damit zu tun, was einem Muttersprachler leichter von der Zunge geht. Irgendwie scheint es mir natürlicher, und fällt mir leichter, *Rot-Grün* zu sagen, anstatt *Grün-Rot*.

---

Anders verhält es sich, wenn eine Gewichtung ins Spiel kommt. Wie zum Beispiel mit

> > Kupfer-Zinn-Legierung<sup>2</sup>

im Gegensatz zu

> > Zinn-Kupfer-Legierung

Den letzteren Begriff wird man nicht verwenden, da für die praktische Anwendung dieses Materials, der Kupferanteil normalerweise höher ist, als der des Zinns (und ggf. weiterer Metallzusätze), und deshalb zuerst genannt wird.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>[Rot-Grün-Sehschwäche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot-Gr%C3%BCn-Sehschw%C3%A4che)</sub>

<sup>2)</sup><sub>Beschreibend für [*"Bronze"*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze)</sub>