# Kann man Hauptwörter in Zusammensetzungen als Eigenschaft bezeichnen?

Tags: word-usage, adjective, reference-request

Bezugnehmend auf [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/hei%c3%9ft-es-schinken-k%c3%a4se-oder-k%c3%a4se-schinken-croissant)

> #### Heißt es Schinken-Käse- oder Käse-Schinken-Croissant?
>
> ... welche **Eigenschaft** bei derartig zusammengesetzten Wörtern zuerst genannt wird?

Kann man in diesem Zusammenhang Hauptwörter wie *"Wurst"*, *"Schinken"* oder *"Käse"* als
*Eigenschaft* (Adjektiv) z.B. eines belegten Brötchens bezeichnen?
Ist das korrekt?

Ich würde mich freuen, wenn das jemand mit einer Referenz und weiteren Beispielen belegen könnte.

---

Aus dem Englischen<sup>1</sup> ist mir der Begriff des *adjective noun* bekannt, aber dieser bezeichnet eigentlich die gegenteilige Transformation, nämlich eines Adjektivs zu einem Nomen, wie z.B. in

> > *reich => Die Reichen*

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Meine Muttersprache ist Deutsch</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es ist zwar nicht sehr gebräuchlich, aber man kann auch ein Nomen als Eigenschaft bezeichnen, und zwar dann, wenn dieses ein wesentliches, charakteristisches Merkmal wird. Bei einem Croissant wäre eine solches Merkmal *Käse* oder *Schinken* oder beides.

Beispiele:

> - er prägt sich in dieser Eigenschaft [als schwarzer Mann] ihrer Phantasie ein *Klemperer LTI96* <sup>[DWDS: Eigenschaft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Eigenschaft)</sup>
> - in meiner Eigenschaft als Hausverwalter <sup>[DWDS: Eigenschaft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Eigenschaft)</sup>
> - Das neue Wort kennzeichnet meistens eine besondere Eigenschaft oder ein besonderes Merkmal (Strohhut: der Hut, der aus Stroh gefertigt wurde). <sup>[Lernhelfer](https://www.lernhelfer.de/schuelerlexikon/deutsch/artikel/zusammensetzung-kompositum)</sup>
> - exozentrisches Kompositum, bei dem das zweite Glied nicht determiniert wird, sondern sich auf eine prominente Eigenschaft des Gemeinten bezieht. Beispiel: Dickkopf (nicht ein dicker Kopf, sondern eine starrsinnige Person), Milchgesicht <sup>[Mediensprache](https://www.mediensprache.net/de/basix/lexikon/index.aspx?qu=Kompositum)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

An sich sind fast alle zusammengesetzten Substantive die Beschreibung eines *Merkmals* oder einer Eigenschaft. Das letzte Wort ist immer *das Ding an sich*, die vorangehenden beschreiben nur die Merkmale.

> Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft

(nein, ich habe keine Lust, das ganz hinzuschreiben...)

Von rechts nach links gelesen werden die Eigenschaftsbeschreibungen immer detaillierter:

> Eine Gesellschaft, die Fahrten mit Schiffen, die mit Dampf betrieben werden, auf der Donau anbietet.

Die Schreibung mit Bindestrich ist allerdings ein bißchen anders, ein

> Bauernschinkenbrötchen

ist etwas anderes als ein (kannibalisches)

> Bauern-Schinken-Brötchen

hier liest man nämlich von links nach rechts und die Zusammensetzung ist nur eine *Aufzählung*, keine *Einschachtelung*. Hier werden auch keine Merkmale oder EIgenschaften, sondern *Bestandteile* aufgezählt. Und ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass die Sortierung nach der angenommenen Wichtigkeit von links nach rechts erfolgt oder keine Priorisierung vorliegt (d.h. entweder ist der größte Bestandteil links oder alle sind gleich, aber der größte Bestandteil steht nie rechts).

In einer

> Quark-Sahne-Torte

ist mehr Quark als Sahne drin und daher auch in einem

> Schinken-Käse-Croissant

mehr Schinken als Käse.

Comment: _"Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft"_ (skapitän). Lustig das war auch einer meiner ersten Gedanken dazu :-D

Comment: _"und daher auch in einem

Schinken-Käse-Croissant

mehr Schinken als Käse."_ Das würde mich wundern, und wäre eher ungewöhnlich.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich weiß nicht, wo du deine SKCs kaufst, aber da, wo ich meine her habe, ist das so.